# Webdriver and proxy server for firefox

Tags: firefox, proxy, selenium-webdriver, foxyproxy

are there any ways to set firefox's proxy settings? I found here information about FoxyProxy but when Selenium works, plugins are unactivated in window.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Look at [the documentation page](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#using-a-proxy).

Tweaking an existing Firefox profile

You need to change "network.proxy.http" & "network.proxy.http_port" profile settings.

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.addAdditionalPreference("network.proxy.http", "localhost");
profile.addAdditionalPreference("network.proxy.http_port", "3128");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Comment: This might have been correct in 2010, but the addAdditionalPreference method no longer exists on FirefoxProfile setPreference would have to be used to do this via FirefoxProfile.  In addition in order to have firefox actually use the proxy "network.proxy.type" needs to be set to 1 as Praveen answer mentions or 2 if its a PAC as Saik0 shows.  I use the DesiredCapabilities way of doing this as Dan Seibert's answer shows.

Answer (score 53):

Value for `network.proxy.http_port` should be integer (no quotes should be used) and `network.proxy.type` should be set as 1 (`ProxyType.MANUAL`, Manual proxy settings)

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("network.proxy.type", 1);
profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http", "localhost");
profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http_port", 3128);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Comment: If anybody would tell me how do I set "user:pass@1.1.1.1:2874" in firefox profile it would be much appreciated. I've tried `profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http", "user:pass@1.1.1.1:2874")` but obviously it does NOT work.

Comment: what about proxy authentication?

Comment: @Shane: profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http", "http://user:pass@1.1.1.1") , then profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http_port", 2874) should work.

Comment: @Arya: Well, I actually found `webdriver` too clumsy for lots of work I was trying to do back then, so I turned to `requests`(a python lib) for pure `HTTP/HTTPS` requests to finish my job.

Answer (score 24):

I just had fun with this issue for a couple of days and it was hard for me to find an answer for HTTPS, so here's my take, for Java:

```
    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
    profile.setPreference("network.proxy.type", 1);
    profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http", "proxy.domain.example.com");
    profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http_port", 8080);
    profile.setPreference("network.proxy.ssl", "proxy.domain.example.com");
    profile.setPreference("network.proxy.ssl_port", 8080);
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Gotchas here: enter just the domain and not `http://proxy.domain.example.com`, the property name is `.ssl` and not `.https`

I'm now having even more fun trying to get it to accept my self signed certificates...

Comment: Any luck with self signed certificates? :)

Answer (score 12):

Just to add to the above given solutions.,

Adding the list of possibilities (integer values) for the "network.proxy.type".

```
0 - Direct connection (or) no proxy. 

1 - Manual proxy configuration

2 - Proxy auto-configuration (PAC).

4 - Auto-detect proxy settings.

5 - Use system proxy settings.
```

So, Based on our requirement, the "network.proxy.type" value should be set as mentioned below.

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("network.proxy.type", 1);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Comment: What is your source? How do you know what are the list of possibilities for `network.proxy.type`?

Answer (score 9):

The WebDriver API has been changed. The current snippet for setting the proxy is

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http", "localhost");
profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http_port", "3128");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Comment: what about proxy authentication?

Answer (score 5):

In case if you have an autoconfig URL -

```
        FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
        firefoxProfile.setPreference("network.proxy.type", 2);
        firefoxProfile.setPreference("network.proxy.autoconfig_url", "http://www.etc.com/wpad.dat");
        firefoxProfile.setPreference("network.proxy.no_proxies_on", "localhost");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile);
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a java example using `DesiredCapabilities`. I used it for pumping selenium tests into jmeter. (was only interested in HTTP requests)

```
import org.openqa.selenium.Proxy;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

String myProxy = "localhost:7777";  //example: proxy host=localhost port=7777
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY,
                           new Proxy().setHttpProxy(myProxy));
WebDriver webDriver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
```

Answer (score 4):

For PAC based urls

```
 Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
 proxy.setProxyType(Proxy.ProxyType.PAC);
 proxy.setProxyAutoconfigUrl("http://some-server/staging.pac");
 DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
 capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);
 return new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
```

I hope this could help.

Comment: How to authenticate in this proxy?? I am trying as `http://code:Blue%4019@proxypath.pac`. But I am unable to load any page.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [latest documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/http_proxies/)

```
from selenium import webdriver

PROXY = "<HOST:PORT>"
webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX['proxy'] = {
    "httpProxy": PROXY,
    "ftpProxy": PROXY,
    "sslProxy": PROXY,
    "proxyType": "MANUAL",

}

with webdriver.Firefox() as driver:
    # Open URL
    driver.get("https://selenium.dev")
```

Answer (score 2):

Firefox Proxy: JAVA

```
String PROXY = "localhost:8080";

org.openqa.selenium.Proxy proxy = new org.openqa.selenium.Proxy();

proxy.setHttpProxy(PROXY)setFtpProxy(PROXY).setSslProxy(PROXY);

DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();

cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy); 

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(cap);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution, i looked for because a had problems with code like this (it s set the system proxy in firefox):

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http", "localhost");
profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http_port", "8080");
driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

I prefer this solution, it force the proxy manual setting in firefox.
To do that, use the org.openqa.selenium.Proxy object to setup Firefox :

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
localhostProxy.setProxyType(Proxy.ProxyType.MANUAL);
localhostProxy.setHttpProxy("localhost:8080");
profile.setProxyPreferences(localhostProxy);
driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

if it could help...

Answer (score 0):

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
String PROXY = "xx.xx.xx.xx:xx";
OpenQA.Selenium.Proxy proxy = new OpenQA.Selenium.Proxy();
proxy.HttpProxy=PROXY;
proxy.FtpProxy=PROXY;
proxy.SslProxy=PROXY;
profile.SetProxyPreferences(proxy);
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

It is for C#

Answer (score -4):

Preferences -> Advanced -> Network -> Connection (Configure how Firefox connects to the Internet)

Comment: I know this. When Selenium runs firefox window for work the connection tab with proxies is empty.