# Firefox is not navigating to the URL and TestWise is showing timeout errror (Rspec, Selenium WebDriver)

Tags: ruby, firefox, rspec, selenium-webdriver, testwise

I am learning `rspec` with `selenium webdriver` using `testwise`. I created a project and given a url and created a new test case and tried to run it. While running it is opening Firefox automatically.but not navigating to the given url(gmail.com)

Here's my code

```
load File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/test_helper.rb'

describe "Test Suite" do
  include TestHelper

  before(:all) do    
    @browser = $browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for(browser_type)
    @browser.navigate.to(site_url)
  end

  after(:all) do
    @browser.quit unless debugging?
  end

  it "New Test Case" do
    # Test Steps go here
  end

end
```

Comment: might be a proxy issue. Set a proxy for firefox as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887978/webdriver-and-proxy-server-for-firefox

Comment: I use the form: `@browser.goto uri`

Comment: What version of selenium/ruby are you using? Older versions are not working with the newest firefox anymore.

Comment: Thanks..I uninstalled and installed FF and i use jmeter too on FF.May be due to proxy i couldn't get it. Thanks ppl :)