# browsermob-proxy 'server is refusing connections' error

Tags: browsermob

Selenium Webdriver 2.42.2, browsermob-proxy Beta 9, Windows 7/Firefox

I am trying to call the browsermob-proxy API to capture http network requests and after following this [example](http://assertselenium.com/2012/11/02/performance-data-collection-using-browsermob-proxy-and-selenium/). But, I get the following errors:

```
The proxy server is refusing connections
```

Firefox is configured to use a proxy server that is refusing connections.

```
Check the proxy settings to make sure that they are correct.
Contact your network administrator to make sure the proxy server is working.
```

Anyone know if this could be a network issue, we do not use proxy servers in our network. I have also run the browsermob-proxy.bat -port 9090 to startup the server. Below is a sample of the code I've tried:

```
public void setDriver(String browser,String environment,String platform) throws Exception {
ProxyServer server = null;

// start the proxy
server = new ProxyServer(9091);
server.start();
server.setCaptureHeaders(true);
server.setCaptureContent(true);

// set the Selenium proxy object
Proxy proxy = server.seleniumProxy();
//Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
//proxy.setHttpProxy("localhost:9091");

caps = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY,proxy);

server.newHar("test");

public void closeDriver() throws Exception {
Har har = server.getHar(); // browserMob proxy

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:/Downloads/browserMob.har");
har.writeTo(fos); // browserMob proxy
server.cleanup(); // browserMob proxy
server.stop(); // browserMob proxy

this.driver.quit();
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 variants:
1) Browsermob Proxy Server didn't start;
2) Proxy Server started with wrong parametres;

If you have the second problem, try this code:

```
                server = new ProxyServer(9091);     
                server.setLocalHost(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"));
                server.start();
                server.setCaptureContent(true);
                server.setCaptureHeaders(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

As described above, but a couple of thoughts:

1. Try using Firefox profile:
   As described in here: [Webdriver and proxy server for firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887978/webdriver-and-proxy-server-for-firefox)
2. Try to add address parameter by: `InetAddress.getLocalHost()`
3. Make sure port is open.