# What is reason for Firefox web browser connection setting change to "use system proxy setting"?

Tags: firefox, selenium, proxy, selenium-webdriver

I use default browser as Firefox. I have set to connection setting to "Manual Proxy Configuration " and has added localhost to proxy by pass. But when I'm trying to load localhost web address through selenium web driver that automatically change the proxy setting to "use system proxy setting " and my localhost web addresses not working. How can I chage it

Comment: @alecxe problem is "addAdditionalPreference"  method is not shown under FirefoxProfile(). Is there any other method?

Comment: yeah, try other answers in that topic. [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5166310/771848) should work.

Comment: On Kubuntu Linux I had this same issue. Setting `network.proxy.type` to 0 in the anonymous profile resolved that.