# Use of Proxy in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I have a website that I want to test through automation. My client wants to test the website using a proxy of another country as we can testing manual using Browserc Extension. How we can perform it in selenium using java. Below is the code I tried but how can I check this is the same country that proxy I used.

`

```
    Proxy proxy= new Proxy();
    proxy.setHttpProxy("localhost:8888");
    DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
    cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY,  proxy);
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "G:\\Selenium\\Driver\\geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://vapesuite.co.uk/#/");`
```

Comment: i think you are trying to verify the country and to do so try to open the https://mylocation.org/ and check whether you are able to get the desired location or not. This will confirm the correct working of your proxy.

Comment: @AbhishekDhoundiyal yes you are right, can you please guide me how to implement this.

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53774638/5372079

Comment: @AbhishekDhoundiyal I try this but it not loading the page and through timeout error on browser.

Comment: Are you sure your VPN is working fine? Open normal firefox browser and set the proxy manually and verify that your proxy is working or not.

Comment: @AbhishekDhoundiyal yes it's working fine manually. Please check screenshot of my code:  https://prnt.sc/18qffql

Comment: @AbhishekDhoundiyal please check browser error: https://prnt.sc/18qg201

Comment: As per the screenshot, there is some issue with the proxy configuration. Try using the code below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is with your code and proxy and it is not working properly.

I have tried the free proxy and it was working fine for me, please see the attached screenshot.

**Code Used:**

```
    FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();

    profile.setPreference("network.proxy.type", 1);
    profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http", "116.80.41.12");
    profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http_port", 80);
    profile.setPreference("network.proxy.ssl", "116.80.41.12");
    profile.setPreference("network.proxy.ssl_port", 80);

    options.setProfile(profile);

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
    driver.get("https://vapesuite.co.uk/#/");
```

**https://free-proxy-list.net/**
[image]

[image]

**https://mylocation.org/**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you are using maven this should work for you :
https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html