# selenium webdriver firefox - how to disable requests by myme-types?

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, webdriver, mime-types

Does WebDriver (Firefox) have ability for disable requests by mime-types? 
I have one html page. In it i have css and js files load + some images. 
Need make one browser request to this page, but without load a text/css content. After that i need make more one request to this page, with text/css content, but without application/javascript content. And in the end, more one page load, but without only image/png. Is it possible? If not, may be some extensions for Firefox can help me?
I tried found solution with small proxy on python (filtering requests by content-type), but this relation have many troubles.

Answer (score 0):

Your basic options are:

- configure your target browser to disable CSS, javascript or images. For example, it can be done by tweaking the `about:config` in Firefox, see:
  [Do not want images to load and CSS to render on Firefox in Selenium WebDriver tests with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157994/do-not-want-images-to-load-and-css-to-render-on-firefox-in-selenium-webdriver-te)
- install a browser addon and configure it's preferences. For firefox, there is [`Web Developer`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/), [`QuickJava`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/quickjava/) and I'm sure there are others.
- use a proxy like `polipo`, `squid`, `privoxy` .. there are so many (your current approach), see: [Webdriver and proxy server for firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887978/webdriver-and-proxy-server-for-firefox)